# Problem with homography when stitching aerial drone images?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a series of 20 aerial photographs taken from a drone, which are not particularly in order. I am trying to use the opencv stitcher api to stitch them all together. For starters, I tried to write a bit of code to just stitch two of the photos together, however I think there is a problem with my homography. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
import sys

img1 = cv2.imread('images/00000710.png', 0)   
img1 = cv2.blur(img1,(5,5))
h1, w1 = img1.shape[:2]
img2 = cv2.imread('images/00000711.png', 0)
img2 = cv2.blur(img2,(5,5))
h2, w2 = img2.shape[:2]

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, desc1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, desc2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)

#matches
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(desc1, desc2, k=2)
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x[0].distance)
good = [m1 for (m1, m2) in matches if m1.distance < 0.7 * m2.distance]

src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1,1,2)

H, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
pts = np.float32([[0,0],[0,h1-1],[w1-1,h1-1],[w1-1,0]]).reshape(-1,1,2)

warped_img = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, H, (1200,1200))
cv2.imwrite('warped.jpg', warped_img)

stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)
result = stitcher.stitch((img1, warped_img))

cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', result[1])
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ySam.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apzcl.png)

I've never done anything like this but I've read many guides online and I've seen the documentation. However, the warped image does not look correct and this code outputs a blank jpg -- not even all black or all white, it just simply gives an error when opening the image file. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your stitcher probably failed. The return from `stitcher.stitch()` is a tuple where the first value indicates failure or success, the second is the image. If the image is `None`, then your stitcher is failing. I'm a little confused at your code---the stitcher class itself will warp the images, you do not need to do it manually. Also, I'm not sure if your code above is *exactly* what you're running, but you have a typo; both `detectAndCompute()` methods are running on `img1`.

Comment: Can I just pass all 20 images to the stitch function then? What do I do if it fails?

Comment: I've never used the stitcher class in OpenCV so I don't have a lot of suggestions unfortunately, and there's not great resources for Python out there with it. There is, however, a large C++ example from OpenCV that you may be able to gleam some light from: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp. Also, there's this tutorial which may or may not help: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html